# Alter assembly in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, deployment

we have database with some table-valued functions writen in C#. I have database project in visual studio, where I use "Deploy" action from Solution Explorer. However, when I want "alter" assembly and functions on testing database server from my developing database server I must manually (now semi-scripted) drop functions and assembly, then create assembly and create functions.

In 99% cases we don't change interface (function names, column names, column types, etc...).

Is there some easy way how to alter assembly and related functions/procedures?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer seems to be that there is no other way.

Dropping and re-creating the assembly and linked functions is the only way for the database engine to validate that your interfaces are valid (and validly referenced).

**EDIT**

Metadata about the relationship between assemblies and referencing functions is stored in the `sys.assembly_modules` table:

```
SELECT *, OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) FROM sys.assembly_modules
```

It's pretty easy to generate the drop scripts from this metadata:

```
DECLARE @assembly_name sysname
SET @assembly_name = '<your assembly name>'


SELECT 'drop function ' + OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID)
FROM sys.assemblies AS a
JOIN sys.assembly_modules AS am
ON   am.assembly_id = a.assembly_id
WHERE a.name = @assembly_name

SELECT 'drop assembly ' + @assembly_name
```

Generating the create scripts is much harder because there's no way to know whether the interface has changed, or the location of the assembly dll to upload.

Comment: I have no problem with recreating, unless the recreating must I do manually. I search for some way like "ALTER ASSEMLBY ...blah_blah_blah..." which automaticly drops and recreate depending objects.

Comment: @TcKs - I'm not sure what you mean - are you looking for a script to drop and create assemblies?

Comment: I'm not sure what exact I should search. However the script, which finds all objects depending on assembly, drop them, drop assembly, create new assembly and create dependent object will be really great and enough for my purposes.

Comment: @TcKs - I did a bit of poking around in the metadata; generating drop statements is easy (see edit). Generating create statements will be a bit more work, especially since the file system location of the assembly dll will be unknown.